# Do I check what to prepare on my first day of work with my supervisor or the HR?

Tags: internship

I am going to start my internship with a company on 6 December  (in another 12 days).

I am keen to check with the company on the dress code and reporting location. Do I email the company HR or my supervisor to ask about it?

Comment: Since you are asking questions anyway make sure you also know the name of the person you are to ask for and what time you should turn up.  Early in my career I turned up at reception assuming they would know how I am only to hear a bunch of phone calls like "There's someone here at reception, says they are starting today, do you know about that?  No?  Is anyone else hiring?  Ok, then I'll try them.".  I would know the name of the person that interviewed me but that person wouldn't always be available on the morning I arrived.

Comment: You'll need to know how long it takes to get there in the morning, so, if you did a test run, you would probably see what the dress code is.

Answer (score 11):

If they haven't already provided that information and haven't specified who you should contact for these kinds of questions, then I would send one email addressed to both of them. In the same email you can ask if they have a preference for who you should contact for other questions.

You might consider also asking if you can be sent the employee handbook and not just the dress code since that will also answer other questions you might have before your start date.

Answer (score 6):

What you need to know for day#1

1. When to show up
2. Where to show up (some companies have multiple locations, buildings, doors, etc)
3. If applicable: how does commuting work (where to park, receipt for bus ticket, etc)
4. What paperwork to bring (offer letter, social security card, work authorization, insurance stuff, etc.)
5. Any other stuff to bring (phone or laptop for some IT stuffs)

Unless this is VERY formal company, dress business casual and bring some "just in case" food. I would only ask for dress code, if this is customer facing role (sales floor, reception desk). On day 1 observe how your peers are dressed and how they handle food and just do what they do (if that feels right).

Comment: I'd be careful about making any assumptions about the dress code. There are still companies that follow *actual* business professional out there. Showing up on a Monday dressed for casual Friday when your new boss is wearing a tie will make the whole day awkward.

Comment: A notepad and pen would be a good idea.  Don't assume you'll get one from supplies as soon as you arrive - you might not get a chance or they might not even give you things like that for a day or two.  You want to be ready to take notes as you walk and talk from minute one so you don't misremember things - you'll likely be overloaded with info first day.

Comment: Yeah I've tended to show up dressed very smart for my first day; it's not going to hurt. It's often the case that official dress policies don't match what your team is doing - I've been to some where officially there was no dress code but everyone wore something smart, and the converse where technical make a point of dressing scruffy and sales/admin have on suits and ties.